# Changes to oAuth allowing multiple users use same qb app

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have been working on building an intuit quickbooks online app. During this time I have been using multiple users on the same quickbooks company account to test the initial flow of the application. This all worked fine until 12/20/2012 when I started getting this error:

Oops! An error has occurred.

Please close this window and try again.

Error Code: invalid_database
Message: The application has already been subscribed to by another user for this company

Did something recently change? Or is there a way to configure the application to allow this?

Comment: What's the user-case for this? Why would you want more than one user to connect to the same QuickBooks file?

Comment: Right now with quickbooks online you can have multiple users associated to the same company account (even a accountant). If one of them adds the app we setup a user for them on our side which the other user won't have the login information for. Thus can't see our data that we calculate. We would like to allow everyone on that account to setup an account with us.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to store one set of OAuth credentials per company file in your app, and always use those regardless of what actual user is logged in to your app? The way you're doing it, the net result is the same functionality, at a higher price (since Intuit charges per connection).

Comment: Keith is right.  You want to use the company owner's OAuth tokens to also serve other users how belong the same company.  it is correct that this change was made w/ the recent IPP 3.9 release to prevent developers from creating these "unnecessary" connections.

Comment: I understand but if customer comes to my site and wants to connect their Quickbooks and doesn't know that someone else has already setup the oAuth how can I verify who they are if the oAuth process fails because someone else has already set it up? Wouldn't it be better if instead of stopping the user during oAuth process it returned to me that the user was verified and they are associated to this account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your use case. Only the administrator of QuickBooks can setup the sync or grant access to a 3rd party app. You would know the user belongs to the same company and you would also know if that company has already been granted access. So there should be no confusion. Random users wont be authorizing access

regards
Jarred