# Using multiple QuickBooks Online companies with one Oauth connection (QBO v3)

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

This question involves Intuit's [QBO v3 API](https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO).

I have one user ID that has access multiple companies. Affiliates, etc. I'm getting authentication errors when I try to connect to companies other than the first one I queried. Is this because each OAuth connection only gets to talk to one company?

I don't remember specifying a company in the access token acquisition process, so I'm confused about this. I thought [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973954/changes-to-oauth-allowing-multiple-users-use-same-qb-app) might be responsive, but it didn't quite address my question.

Answer (score 6):

Each set of OAuth credentials is tied *to one specific QuickBooks company*.

It's impossible to have a single set of OAuth credentials that's tied to multiple QuickBooks Online companies.

You should be connecting multiple times (once for each company) and storing the OAuth tokens separately for each QuickBooks Online company. When you go through the OAuth connection process, you'll be asked specifically which QuickBooks Online company you want to connect to.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I guess what I'm still a little confused about is that my QBOE account (identified by a single email / pwd credential set) has access to multiple companies. (When I login, I'm asked to select which company and I can switch between them. As I think about it, in every additional company was shared by another QBOE user.) Are you saying that there's a one-to-one relationship in QBOE between accounts and companies? This would be in contrast to the situation with QB Desktop where one software license includes a theoretically unlimited number of companies.

Comment: There is a one-to-one relationship between a specific OAuth token and a QuickBooks Online company. There is also a one-to-one relationship between a specific OAuth token and a QuickBooks for Windows company file. It has nothing to do with usernames at all - it's a relationship between the actual company itself and the OAuth credentials.

Comment: Very helpful, Keith. Appreciate you clearing this up. I see as I go through the workflow again that the resource owner authorizes an app for a specific company.